# Injectionmembers in Unity Application Block 1.1 vs 3

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

For a software application I am developing in C#, I am using dependency injection.
For compatibility reasons (users with Windows XP), I need to target .NET framework version 4.0.

I developed the application with Microsoft Application Block 3, which minimally needs .NET 4.5, using the RegisterType method like this:

```
 InjectionMember[] im = { new InjectionConstructor() };
 LifetimeManager transient = new TransientLifetimeManager();
 container.RegisterType<IInterface, CImplementation>(@"name", transient, im);
```

Switching back to Application Block 1.1, it seems the RegisterType<> method is missing the overloads which specify the injection members.

I can't seem to do more than

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, CImplementation>(@"name", transient);
```

How do I tell RegisterType<> that I want to specify injection members?

Comment: Why not use [Unity 2](https://unity.codeplex.com/releases/view/31277).

Comment: I will give that a try, actually i thought Unity 2 doesn't support XP as well. I see I am mistaken.

Comment: Unity2 works as well, thank you for the hint, @Steven

Answer (score 0):

By adding this line

```
container.RegisterInstance<IUnityContainer>(container);
```

I was able to have it call my constructor:

```
public CImplementation(IUnityContainer container)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(@"CImplementation(IUnityContainer container)");
}
```